# Customising the layout of Pagerfanta pagination with a custom template

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, twig, pagerfanta

I have Pagerfanta installed and working, however I am having difficulty in customising the layout. I read on [Github](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle#custom-template) that I need to pass through `my_template`, however I am unsure where this should be configured and what specificially this refers to.

**Custom template**

If you want to use a custom template, add another argument

```
<div class="pagerfanta">
    {{ pagerfanta(my_pager, 'my_template') }}
</div>
```

Ideally I would like to have my own Twig template that I can modify, however I don’t know if Pagerfanta supports this. Is it all done in PHP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think it supports Twig templates but for sure you can write your custom `Template` class to render the pagination however you want.

Let's say in your AppBundle, you will need to create `MyCustomTemplate` class which should extend [Pagerfanta\View\Template\DefaultTemplate](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta/blob/master/src/Pagerfanta/View/Template/DefaultTemplate.php):

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Template;

use Pagerfanta\View\Template\DefaultTemplate;

class MyCustomTemplate extends DefaultTemplate
{
    // override whatever you need here ...
}
```

then register it in your services.yml file together with the view service:

```
services:
    acme_app.template.my_template:
        class: Acme\AppBundle\Template\MyCustomTemplate

    pagerfanta.view.my_template:
        class: Pagerfanta\View\DefaultView
        public: false
        arguments:
            - "@acme_app.template.my_template"
        tags: [{ name: pagerfanta.view, alias: my_template }]
```

then in your Twig templates you will be able to use:

```
{{ pagerfanta(my_pager, 'my_template') }}
```

which will result in displaying your custom pagination template.

Answer (score 0):

`my_template` is the alias of your view. The next section in the Github link you have provided explains more.

It would look something like this

```
services:
    app.view.my_template:
        class: App\View\MyView
        public: false
        tags: [{ name: pagerfanta.view, alias: my_template }]
```