# Symfony2 Pager Fanta

Tags: php, symfony, pagerfanta

Is it posible to set the route / render controller with pager fanta in symfony2 because i have tried rendering a controller and it hits me with cannot generate route:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as such route does not exist.") in @AppBundle\Survey\table_questions.html.twig at line 27.
```

On line 27 i have

```
{{ pagerfanta(pager, 'twitter_bootstrap3') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you use the `WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle` but you can set your default view: https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle#adding-views. Also see this answer: [Customising the layout of Pagerfanta pagination with a custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504564/customising-the-layout-of-pagerfanta-pagination-with-a-custom-template/35507413#35507413).

Alternatively, the `pagerfanta` function takes a third argument with options to create the route generator. https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle/blob/master/Twig/PagerfantaExtension.php#L100.

Notably `routeName` might be enough for what you need to do:

```
{{ pagerfanta(pager, 'twitter_bootstrap3', {routeName: 'route_name'}) }}
```

Comment: actually it worked with routeName only because i have defaults for page. but you gave me more info  that i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
{{ pagerfanta(pager, 'twitter_bootstrap3', {'routeName': 'your_route_name'}) }}
```